# How to find the constant of an expanded binomial expression?

Tags: constants

Can somebody please explain how to find the Constant Term in an Expanded Binomial Expression? I have looked online and a lot of the explanations have confused me. The problem i'm currently on is finding the Constant Term of: 
non-expanded:(x-2)^2 
expanded:**16-32 x+24 x^2-8 x^3+x^4**

Comment: Did you mean $(x-2)^4$ instead of $(x-2)^2$?

Comment: In $(x-2)^2$, or any power $(x-2)^n$, to find the constant term set $x=0$.